Ubuntu Studio installer: 'Device for boot loader installation' is grayed out
I'm trying to install via ubuntustudio-24.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso from a USB disc. The SSD has Windows 10 installed on it and a partition already created for Linux.

I think there might be some issue with Ubuntu Studio and my graphics card (nVidia GTX 660 Ti), but that doesn't explain this bootloader issue. I think? I can get into Ubuntu Studio on this PC but I can't install it.

My spelling and grammar don't need editing, you sad little man. Maybe find something more productive to do with your time. "Greyed" is the correct spelling. Get a life.
